# Vue: how to check if nested input is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have **FormField**, **Form** and **App**. **App** contains **Form** and **Form** contains **FormField** and a button. When a button is clicked I need to check that the `<input>` inside **Form** are not empty. How do I do that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-tdd-wd2nb?file=/src/components/Form.vue

**FormField.vue**

```
<template>

  <input :placeholder= "placeholder"
    
 />

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['placeholder']
}
</script>
```

**Form.vue**

```
<template>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="execute">
    <div  >{{title}}</div>

    <div   v-if="wasError">{{errorMessage}}</div>

    <FormField
               v-for="(field) in fields"
               v-bind:key="field"
               :placeholder="field"
               :name = "field"
    />

    <button  @click="handleClick">Button</button>

  </form>
</template>


<script>

import FormField from "@/components/FormField";

export default {
  components: { FormField},

  props: {
    wasError:  {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false
    },
    errorMessage:  {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    fields: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },

   
  methods: {
    handleClick: function(){
       alert("hello");
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />

  <Form title = "Sign Up"  
             :fields="['Username', 'Email', 'Password']"
             :wasError = "errorStuff.wasError"
             :errorMessage = "errorStuff.errorMessage"/>
 </template>

<script>
import Form from "@/components/Form";

 export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Form
   },


  data()  {
    return {
      fields: [
        'Username', 'Email', 'Password'
      ],
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',

      errorStuff:  {
        wasError: false,
        errorMessage: ''
      }
    }
  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set [`<input>.required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) so that the browser prevents a blank entry upon submitting:

```html
<!-- FormField.vue -->
<input required>
```

If only some fields are required, you'd have to use a `<FormField>` prop for binding. Also note that if `<FormField>`'s root element is the `<input>` itself, you don't have to redeclare `<input>` props, as the root by default inherits any attributes/properties bound on `<FormField>`.

I would update `fields[]` to be an object with `name` and `required` properties that could be used for binding to the `<FormField>` props:

```js
export default {
  data()  {
    return {
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'Username',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'Email',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'Password',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'Nickname',
          required: false,
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Then update the bindings on `<FormField>` to use the new `field` properties:

```html
<FormField v-for="(field) in fields"
           :key="field.name"
           :placeholder="field.name"
           :name="field.name"
           :required="field.required"
/>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/marking-form-inputs-as-required-in-vue-1mxid?file=/src/components/GenericForm.vue)